# Python Pandas Time Series double filter manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have data for 2 years and want to change each day in an automated way like :

```
for year in set(df.index.year):
    for day in set(df[df.index.year == year].index.dayofyear):
        df[df.index.year == year][df.index.dayofyear == day] = 2
```

The strange thing is that setting new values doesn't work at all.
So I use 2 filters at once. The selection works. But changing the value doesn't work.
Does someone share the same problem?
Are there other ways to do so?

Comment: Can you add sample of data and desired output? Maybe help [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Why not `df.index.date == date` with a single loop?

Comment: That is what I need, thank you!
But yes, changing data with double filtering is not supported I think. 
so like e.g.:
df[df.index.year == year][df.index.dayofyear == day] = 2